Problem with delete an entity with @Embedded in Spring Boot
I try to delete cartItem with composite key CartItemId which includes productDetailId and cartId. Everything seems to be going quite well as the result is always 'success', but the database still exists and I don't know why. Please anyone help me
Here's my CartItem entity:
@Getter
@Setter
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class CartItem {

    @EmbeddedId
    CartItemId id;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId("productDetailId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_detail_id")
    ProductDetail productDetail;

    int count;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("cartId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id")
    Cart cart;
}

My CartItemId:
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class CartItemId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "product_detail_id")
    int productDetailId;

    @Column(name = "cart_id")
    int cartId;
}

And my service:
    public String removeCartItem(RemoveCartItemRequest request) {
        int productDetailId = request.getProductDetailId();
        var context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        int userId = Integer.parseInt(context.getAuthentication().getName());

        User user = userRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(() -> new AppException(ErrorCode.NOT_EXISTED));

        int cartId = user.getCart().getCartId();
        CartItemId cartItemId = new CartItemId(productDetailId, cartId);
        cartItemRepository.findById(cartItemId).ifPresent(cartItemRepository::delete);
        return "Success";
    }


I would make it send all the information needed with the RemoveCartItemRequest that saves you queriing and thus performance. Your method doesn't appear to be @Transactional. No transaction nothing will be deleted/persisted.

In RemoveCartItemRequest, I only pass productDetailId and then combining it with cartId from userId that gets from SecurityContextHolder. I also added @Transactional but the result is still the same

@TunazZz maybe cartId is different what you are looking for so you put debug at cartItemId constructor line and check what values are passing to repository findbyId method.

The values are passed correctly, I check cartId and productDetailId also,... And it all exactly the same in the database =(( . I log the value Product Detail ID: 1 Cart ID: 1 CartItem ID cart id: 1 CartItem ID product detail id: 1. I don't know if the problem is from embedded?

I suspect the problem is you still have the thing in memory. Assuming the cart item is in the Cart as well, you should remove it from there. Or use deleteById instead of finding and removing.

Thank you for your help but it didn't work. I found a way that instead of using JPA method to delete cartItem, i created a store procedure and delete it in the database and it worked for me.
